# Mix Django and DRF urls

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So far, I have built a REST API with Django Rest Framework (DRF) which can be consumed by any front-end. Let call this API `backend`.
I am trying to add another Django app (a regular one this time i.e. no DRF) which shares the same models. Let call this app `webapp`

However, it seems that the URLs linked to `webapp` are not available.

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.authtoken import views as token_views
from backend import views
from webapp import views as webapp_views

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet, 'User')
router.register(r'games', views.GameViewSet, 'Game')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^connect/', views.CustomObtainAuthToken.as_view()),
    url(r'membership_create/', views.MembershipCreate.as_view()),
    url(r'auth/connect_with_fb/', views.ConvertTokenViewWithData.as_view()),
    url(r'auth/connect_with_credentials/', views.TokenViewWithData.as_view()),
    url(r'debug/', views.UserLoginAndIdView.as_view()),
    url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework_social_oauth2.urls'),
    url(r'^test/', webapp_views.home, name='test'), # the new view
        )

]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

And the single view (from webapp.views):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("""
        <h1>WEBAPP !</h1>
        <p>test webapp</p>
    """)
```

I am thus wondering if DRF and regular Django views can be mixed so easily or if it is not the right way of doing it.

**EDIT:**

```
Using the URLconf defined in WMC.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^connect/
membership_create/
auth/connect_with_fb/
auth/connect_with_credentials/
debug/
^auth/
^users/$ [name='User-list']
^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='User-detail']
^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/games/$ [name='User-games']
^games/$ [name='Game-list']
^games/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='Game-detail']
The current URL, test/, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: it's correct way of doing it. But, you have to add `$` for better regex.

Comment: Your `name='test'` URL pattern looks OK, it should be available at `/test/`. Note that you are missing `^` from the beginning of some regexes. It's a good idea to use `$` at the end of regexes for individual views as well (but not for `include()`, `admin.site.urls` or routers). At the moment, `r'debug'` matches `/debug/` but also it also matches `/foo/debug/bar/`.

Comment: I have added the Django output when I try to access the `/test/`page.

Comment: You probably haven't restarted your server since adding test - as you can see, all the other URLs in that file are available.

Comment: Restarting is automatically done when I update a file within my project.

Comment: I have also added my project structure for help

Comment: You should restart anyway. It's absolutely clear that your change has not been picked up - adding screenshots of your project layout doesn't help in any way.

Comment: I have launch `manage.py runserver` several times and it does not solve  the problem. I have removed the project structure picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving `url(r'^test/', webapp_views.home, name='test')` before `url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)` solves the problem although I do not know why.

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^test/', webapp_views.home, name='test'),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^connect/', views.CustomObtainAuthToken.as_view()),
        url(r'^membership_create/', views.MembershipCreate.as_view()),
        url(r'^auth/connect_with_fb/', views.ConvertTokenViewWithData.as_view()),
        url(r'^auth/connect_with_credentials/', views.TokenViewWithData.as_view()),
        url(r'^debug/', views.UserLoginAndIdView.as_view()),
        url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework_social_oauth2.urls'),

            )

    ]
```